# How to find several independent paths with certain start/end vertex pairs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Take grid graph as an example.

```
g = GridGraph[{6, 9}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
pairs = {{6, 44}, {54, 33}, {35, 13}, {41, 8}, {14, 26}, {20, 32}};
```

[image]

For each vertex pair, try to find a **simple** path (no need to be shortest), so that all 6 paths meet both conditions:

> 1) each connects vertex 6 and 44, vertex 54 and 33, ..., respectively.
>
> 2) they are all independent, they do not have any vertex in common.

The paths in question need not to be the shortest nor covering all vertices.

One possible sln is:

[image]

It's better to get a **general solution** for any graph and any set of vertex pairs.

With a general solution, one can:

> 1) For a given graph and vertex pairs, solve the total number of slns
>   (0 for no solution), the sln with minimum/maxmum vertices covering...
>
> 2) For a given graph, how many vertex pairs at least are needed to
>   cover all vertices?
>
> 3) What if the end vertex in each pair is unknown but to find the
>   paths covering all vertices?

I'm wondering if there are some typical concepts/discussions behind this kind of question in graph theory. It seems to split the graph into independent parts.

Any thought or keyword suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: There are not 6 such independent paths starting from vertex 6 because this vertex has degree 2. You can find a path that starts with 6-12, one that starts with 6-5, but all the other paths *must* intersect with one of these two. None of the highlighted vertices have degree greater than 4, so it is not possible to have 6 independent paths starting from them.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for your time. one possible sln is added to clarify the question

Comment: I see, so you want *one* shortest path for each of those pairs, but in such a way as to cover all vertices.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, one simple path for each of those pairs, but dont have to be the shortest. And covering all vertices (condition 3)  can also be omitted.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution that will work for any graph, and any set of vertex pairs, and will be able to detect when a solution does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

```
pairs = {{6, 44}, {54, 33}, {35, 13}, {41, 8}, {14, 26}, {20, 32}};
vs = {"Triangle", "Square", "Star", "Rectangle", "Pentagon",  "Diamond"};
vshapes = Thread[Append[Flatten@pairs, Blank[]] -> Append[Riffle[vs, vs], Automatic]];

g = GridGraph[{6, 9}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
  VertexSize -> {Alternatives @@ Flatten[pairs] -> Large}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :> (v /. vshapes)}, 
  VertexStyle -> {Alternatives @@ Flatten[pairs] -> Yellow}]
```

[image]

For each pair `{a,b}` in `pairs` (1) we delete the nodes in `g` that belong to the complement of `{a,b}` in `pairs`, (2)  find *all shortest paths* from `a` to `b` and (3) discard the paths that, if deleted from `g`, would make some pair in `pairs` disconnected. For a pair that does not have such a path in the first round, we repeat the process deleting the vertices that belong to the paths already found.

```
ClearAll[keep, indepPaths]
keep[g_, prs_][pth_] := Max[GraphDistance[
      VertexDelete[g, Union[Complement[Flatten[prs], {##}], pth]], ##] & @@@ 
    DeleteCases[prs, pth[[{1, -1}]]]] < Infinity

indepPaths[g_, prs_, u_: {}] := Module[{vd = VertexDelete[g,
       Complement[Union[u, Flatten[prs]], {##}]]}, 
    Select[keep[g, prs]]@ FindPath[vd, ##, {GraphDistance[vd, ##]}, All]] &;
```

For the example in OP, we find single paths for 4 of the pairs and no paths for two pairs in the first round:

```
as1 = Association[{##} -> indepPaths[g, pairs][##] & @@@ pairs]
```

> ```
>  <|{6, 44} -> {{6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44}}, 
> {54, 33} -> {}, 
> {35, 13} -> {}, 
> {41, 8} -> {{41, 40, 34, 28, 22, 16, 10, 9, 8}}, 
> {14, 26} -> {{14, 15, 21, 27, 26}}, 
> {20, 32} -> {{20, 19, 25, 31, 32}}|>
> ```

In the second round the paths connecting the two pairs are found:

```
as2 = Association[{##} -> indepPaths[g, pairs, Flatten@Values@as1][##] & @@@ 
    Select[indepPaths[g, pairs][##] & @@ # == {} &][pairs]]
```

> ```
>  <|{54, 33} -> {{54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 43, 37, 38, 39, 33}},
>  {35, 13} -> {{35, 29, 23, 17, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 13}}|>
> ```

```
as12 = Map[First]@Join[as1, as2]
```

> ```
>  <|{6, 44} -> {6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44}, 
>  {54, 33} -> {54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 43, 37, 38, 39, 33}, 
>  {35, 13} -> {35, 29, 23, 17, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 13}, 
>  {41, 8} -> {41, 40, 34, 28, 22, 16, 10, 9, 8}, 
>  {14, 26} -> {14, 15, 21, 27,  26},
>  {20, 32} -> {20, 19, 25, 31, 32}|>
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[g, Style[PathGraph[ as12@#], AbsoluteThickness[5]] & /@ pairs]
```

[image]

There may be multiple paths for a given pair in a given round. In that case, we need to consider all combinations of disjoint paths for the second round processing.

Comment: Ingenious pruning tech. 1) The indepPaths function uses shortest path,  there would be more alternative paths in as1 with longer lengths.   2) When no paths pairs (i.e. {54, 33} and {35, 13} in question) appear, as2 searches down. How about searching up as of 1) ? 3) How to find exactly **all** the slns?

Comment: @bigheadghost, great points. Perhaps we can change  `{GraphDistance[vd, ##]}` to a range (that is, `{0, k}+GraphDistance[vd, ##]`), iterate over `k` until we get a non-empty path list for every pair, and select a pairwise-disjoint combination from `Values@as1`.